# Permissions for sending SMS

Tags: android, android-studio

I was wondering what did I do wrong? I know with sdk version 24+ I need to get some extra runtime permissions, but I tried a lot of them and nothing worked so far.. So here is the code, I added the last part with permission request but its still not working, app opens but when I click on button app crashes.. Anyone knows what is wrong?

CODE FROM MAIN_ACTIVITY:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageView imageView;
Button button;
boolean running;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    running = false;

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(!running){
            ((AnimationDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).start();
            running = true;}

            SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage("+3564245237",null,"1", null, null);

            int GET_MY_PERMISSION = 1;
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)){

                }
                else{

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},GET_MY_PERMISSION);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    );
}
```

}

I ALSO HAVE THIS IN MY MANIFEST :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your [onRequestPermissionResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int, java.lang.String[], int[]))?

it looks like its calling back to nothing.

Are you sure you are calling requestPermissions? if shouldShouldRequestPermissionRationale is false, then nothing happens.

Comment: you are probably right.. I am so confused about this permissions.. Im also not that expirienced at programming actually im a beginner so I have no idea what did I do wrong.. So what are you suggesting?